# Find the attribute_id by attribute_code

Tags: magento-1.7, image, mysql, product-attribute

I need to find the `attribute_id` values of the attributes `image`, `small_image` and `thumbnail`. I know them for my database - 85, 86 and 87, but I need to make my query dynamic, instead of with hard-coded values. What I struggle with is to find in which table the attributes are stored. I checked `catalog_product_attribute` but there is no column with the `name/code` of the attributes.

I need to acquire them as an SQL query, not as `Mage::...` PHP code.
A sample SQL query code or any other guidance will be very helpful.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', $attributeCode);
$id = $attribute->getId();
```

if `$id` is `null` then the attribute does not exist.
It works the same for getting category attributes, customer attributes and customer address attributes.

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_category', 'is_anchor');
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'gender');
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer_address', 'postcode');
```

**[EDIT]**
Apparently I can't read. I missed the line that stated `sql query`.
Here is a query also:

```
SELECT 
    e.attribute_id 
FROM 
    eav_attribute e
LEFT JOIN
    eav_entity_type t 
ON e.entity_type_id = t.entity_type_id
WHERE 
    e.attribute_code = 'image' AND
    t.entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'
```

Comment: I went with an easier solution: `SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'image' AND frontend_input = 'media_image'`, but thanks for showing me that I have to look in `eav_attribute` table. :)

Comment: Your approach is risky because there could be an other attribute with the same code for a different entity

Answer (score 1):

I used this codes for getting the attribute ID in **eav_attribute** tables

```
$attribute_code = 'image';

$eavCollections = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getCollection()
                    ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_code', array('eq'=> $attribute_code ));

                foreach($eavCollections as $eavCollection){
                   $attribute_id = $eavCollection['attribute_id']; //get the attribute id
                   echo $attribute_id;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Short and helpful:

```
Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getIdByCode('catalog_product', 'color');
```