# get the deleted attribute back to the live site

Tags: attributes, database, eav

we missly deleted the attribute : "age" from live site.

attribute code : "age" attribute label : Age group

we assigned this  attribute to thousands of products.

is there any option to get that attribute back in database?

we have a yesterday database backup.

is i have to export the **eav_attribute** table from yesterday database and import to the current database?....

for this to do, **is i have to delete the eav_attribute table from current database?**

or is there any option to export and import only particular attribute instead of "eav_attribute" table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete all records from current *eav_attribute* table and  Export eav_attribute table from old database  is not good idea.

`eav_attribut`e table is master table for all `magento eav` attribute like `eav_attribute_group,eav_attribute_label,eav_attribute_option,eav_attribute_option_value,eav_attribute_set etc`.

As,you have delete all records  and import all records that will created issue  in import as primary key automatically increase.

Better idea to  create same attribute at current system and  export  product/customer's  related this attribute  value in database.

Comment: i did't got this line : "export product/customer's related this attribute value in database. "

Comment: we already assigned thousands of products to that attribute. if we create new attribute again we have to allocate all thousand of products to that attribute.

Comment: hey,ur problem is solved or not?

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to delete the full eav_attribute table.
Just restore your backup in a different database.
Export your `age`  attribute.  You can use phpmyadmin, it's easier.
You should get something like this:

```
INSERT INTO eav_attribute (attribute_id, ...) VALUES (99, ....);
```

99 is just a placeholder. The id can be different for you.
Run that query into your live database.
Then look in the table `catalog_eav_attribute` for the record with the same id as above (99 in my example). Export that row and import it in your live database.
If the attribute is not a dropdown attribute, just look in your backup for the attribute values from that attribute.
If the attribute type is `int` look in the table `catalog_product_entity_int`, if it's varchar look in `catalog_product_entity_varchar` and so on.
to get the values run this

```
SELECT * FROM {table} where attribue_id = 99;
```

Where `{table}` is the table described above and 99 is your actual attribute id.
Export these values and import them in your live database.
Then look in the table `eav_attribute_group` for records with `attribute_id` equal to your attribute id (99 in my example) and do the same. Export the rows from your backup and import them in your live db.
Then reindex everything.
If your attribute is a dropdown or multiselect you need to search for the options also and it's a bit more complicated.

Comment: INSERT INTO eav_attribute (attribute_id, ...) VALUES (99, ....);  = > giving error = >   #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '..) VALUES (99, ....)' at line

Comment: Did you take the query that I posted and ran it on your live db? That was just an example. You should get different values.  Please backup your live db before trying anything else.

Comment: how to find the attribute id ? is i have to follow this : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14855/find-the-attribute-id-by-attribute-code ? or is i have to place existed attribute code in the query you gave to me

Comment: `SELECT * FROM eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'age'`. This will get you the line you need from your backup. Then export this line, and import it in your live db. Just curious, are your even reading the answers or you're just copy-pasting queries hoping it will work?

Comment: i executed that command : http://prntscr.com/9lyozr than i searched in catalog.eav.attribute , i can see line with attribute id 99 : http://prntscr.com/9lypq5 i exported this. and imported to live database. but i am getting this error : http://prntscr.com/9lyqg7 and this is dropdown attribute. sorry that i am new to database.

Comment: when i searched with other attribute code "barcodeid", its displaying results .

SELECT * FROM eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'barcodeid'  , but for age its showing zero results . please guide me about this

Comment: Sorry. I quit. I have no other ideas.

Answer (score 2):

three table you need to update according to your previous values

**first**

`eav_attribute`  if you have backup of this table then execute the insert query.

**second**

`eav_attribute_option`   add attribute option according to that attribute

**third**

`eav_attribute_option_value`  add the options values.. find the option_id and insert those too..

after that you have to set the attribute to attribute set.

Answer (score 2):

I think I am late but I face the same problem. I have deleted one of the attribute in our live site that is assigned to many products. It was a select attribute. What worked for me it was just adding that attribute in **EAV_ATTRIBUTE** table and all options and its value automatically comes without inserting it so I think Magento does not delete options and its values

I have run following SQL query in my PHP Myadmin

```
INSERT INTO `eav_attribute` (`attribute_id`, `entity_type_id`, `attribute_code`, `attribute_model`, `backend_model`, `backend_type`, `backend_table`, `frontend_model`, `frontend_input`, `frontend_label`, `frontend_class`, `source_model`, `is_required`, `is_user_defined`, `default_value`, `is_unique`, `note`) VALUES (136, 4, 'Test', NULL, NULL, 'int', NULL, NULL, 'select', 'Test', NULL, 'eav/entity_attribute_source_table', 0, 1, '', 0, NULL);
```

**Note:** **attribute_id** and **attribute_code** can different so just edit the query accordingly.

Comment: Great solution buddy, Thanks  for that.....